# HP equivalent of the the FindIT Utility

Tags: networking, switch

I think I've lost the configuration on two of my HP-Procurve 1810-24G.  I can't connect with either the previously assigned static or the or the default factory ip.  Are there any utilities equivalent to cisco's find It to get into my switch.

Thanks !

Comment: Personally I would just run a MAC address scanner, identify the HP devices from the OUI and try each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inexpensive web-managed switch. I am afraid It has no managed options other then web interface.

The faced connectivity problem may have two reasons:

1. Manager's IP address restrictions which You did not take into account.
2. VLAN configuration.

As a last resort you can always drop the device to factory defaults:

[HP V1810 Switch Series - How to Reset the Switch to Factory Defaults](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Demr_na-c02828331-1%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&sp4ts.oid=3963985&ac.admitted=1386831537346.876444892.492883150)